# Calculate beam radius for gaussian laser beam with lenses

Tags: optics, laser

So I know that the beam radius is

$$w_R(z) = w_{0R}\left[1+\left(\frac{z\lambda M^2}{\pi w_{0R}^2}\right)^2\right]^{1/2}$$

for a Gaussian beam at a distance $z$.

Now, I need the equation for the beam radius with one lens and with two lenses. I think this equation may mean something for the focused spot radius with one lens:

$$w_F = \frac{\lambda f M ^2}{\pi w_L}$$

Is this correct, and how would this change with two lenses? Basically I want to use two lenses to achieve a certain beam radius given the relevant system parameters. Simple explanation would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: This is solvable by applying the ABCD lens matrix formalism to gaussian beams. Though maybe that's slightly overpowered for what you want.

Comment: This formula can work with two lens only if the object of the second lens is the image of the first one. 
If you do not want the equation but the result you can look at freeware like rezonator. It is efficient for simple optical setup.

Comment: @Aliceo great, thanks. in that case, would f be the focal lengths added together?